# Howto escape maven properties in IntelliJ's file templates

Tags: java, templates, maven, intellij-idea, escaping

I'm trying to create a template for my Maven projects in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 12.

My goal is to escape a predefined maven property inside the template. Unfortunately, the syntax is the same as IntelliJ's parameters in the template.

According to the [online help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/simple-parameterized-and-surround-live-templates.html#param), I can escape a `$` symbol with another `$` in front of it, so my template looks like this (plugin part at the bottom is important):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    #if (${HAS_PARENT})
    <parent>
        <groupId>${PARENT_GROUP_ID}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${PARENT_ARTIFACT_ID}</artifactId>
        <version>${PARENT_VERSION}</version>
        #if (${HAS_RELATIVE_PATH})
        <relativePath>${PARENT_RELATIVE_PATH}</relativePath>
        #end
    </parent>
    #end

    <groupId>${GROUP_ID}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${ARTIFACT_ID}</artifactId>
    <version>${VERSION}</version>

    <!-- global properties -->
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- set jdk version -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>$${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>$${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    ${END}
</project>
```

But with this template, the output is still:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- set jdk version -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>$JDK.VERSION$</source>
                <target>$JDK.VERSION$</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So my question is: How can I get `${jdk.version}` instead of `$JDK.VERSION$` and what's the proper way to escape the String?

Comment: I don't think that this is a great idea at all. Maven offers a feature for this called archetypes: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html

Comment: I understand Archetypes are available and offer more flexibility, but I also want to be able to have Intellij generate a better pom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since IntelliJ uses Apache Velocity as template engine you can use #set to create references.

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.6.4/user-guide.html

use can use

```
#set( $jdk_version = "${jdk.version}" )
```

and inside your template simply reference with **${jdk_version}**

can you test the following example:

```
#set( $jdk_version = "${jdk.version}" )
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    #if (${HAS_PARENT})
    <parent>
        <groupId>${PARENT_GROUP_ID}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${PARENT_ARTIFACT_ID}</artifactId>
        <version>${PARENT_VERSION}</version>
        #if (${HAS_RELATIVE_PATH})
        <relativePath>${PARENT_RELATIVE_PATH}</relativePath>
        #end
    </parent>
    #end

    <groupId>${GROUP_ID}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${ARTIFACT_ID}</artifactId>
    <version>${VERSION}</version>

    <!-- global properties -->
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- set jdk version -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk_version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk_version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    ${END}
</project>
```

that was generating the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>3</groupId>
        <artifactId>4</artifactId>
        <version>5</version>
        <relativePath>7</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>8</groupId>
    <artifactId>9</artifactId>
    <version>10</version>

    <!-- global properties -->
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- set jdk version -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    11
</project>
```

i hope this helps you and is the answer for your question...